# sed replace in file until pattern match

Tags: sed

I use `sed` to do a simple replacement to headers in a file.
Sometimes they need to be replaced, sometimes not.
It works fine, but is long because it reads the the files every time (hundreds of MB).
However there is a pattern that separates the header from the content.

How do I tell `sed` to stop processing the file after encountering a certain pattern ?

Example :

blabla headers that I want to edit here but maybe not FRAME some more content here

Let's say that want to remove "want" from the headers, but the word may or may not be in said headers. I know that I want to stop processing the file at FRAME.

`sed -i '0,/\(pattern1\|pattern2\)/s//pattern1/' * ; # TODO stop at FRAME`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `q` command to quit the sed processing the rest of the input

```
sed -i '0,/\(pattern1\|pattern2\)/s//pattern1/' * ; /FRAME/q'
```

- `/FRAME/` pattern matches the line containing `FRAME` upon which the command `q` is excecuted

**OR**

You can specify an address range from start of the file till it encounters `FRAME` as

```
sed '0, /FRAME/ s/old/new'
```

Comment: Does the second alternative assumes that the file starts with a space ?

Comment: @nha No its an address range. specifiying that the action must be taken from line `0` till pattern `FRAME` is obtained

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '/pattern stop/ {f=1} !f {sub(/old data/,"new data")} 1' file
```

This will replace `old data` with "new data" as long as `pattern stop` is not found.

To write data back to original file:

```
awk 'code'  file > tmp && mv tmp file
```